# `ifconfig -a` and /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg* do not match

Tags: centos, network-interface

I have a CentOS box where the output of `ifconfig -a` shows an `eth1` NIC but, there is no corresponding script at `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1`. Is there any way to make sure this doesn't happen? What process generates these networking scripts, other than manual intervention?

Comment: If you're booting from an existing image (common with virtual machines), the image may have network configuration on disk that was correct in the build environment but that's not accurate for the current host.

Comment: That seems highly likely.