# `Ifconfig -a` shows interfaces w/o IP, `ip show addr` ignores them

Tags: centos, networking

[Recently](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/712052/ifconfig-a-and-etc-sysconfig-network-scripts-ifcfg-do-not-match), I discussed a linux box that was missing a network script for one of its interfaces. Now I have a similar situation. Somehow, an interface `eth1` was installed onto a CentOS box without an IP address. It shows up in `ifconfig eth1` as this:

```
# ifconfig eth1
eth1: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:50:56:a9:cd:2e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I can fix this programmatically by iterating over the interfaces. I prefer to use `ip -o` for scripting purposes because the -o flag says to put everything on one line. Sadly, `ip -o` skips over any interface without an IP, even if I ask specifically for the non-addressed interface:

```
# ip -o addr show dev eth1
# ip addr show dev eth1
4: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:a9:cd:2e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
# ip -o addr show dev eth0
[snip reasonable output]
# echo $?
0
# ip -o addr show dev eth1
# echo $?
0
```

How would you best solve this? I can use a Perl module but I'd prefer using generic shell commands.

Comment: Please specify what you are trying to achieve exactly.

Answer (score 1):

So maybe you have a [custom tool](https://github.com/thrig/scripts/blob/master/network/localaddr.c) that gives a [non-zero exit code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/714188/shell-script-exit-codes) when there is not an address found:

```
[root@localhost]~# ./localaddr -4 enp0s8
[root@localhost]~# echo $?
2
[root@localhost]~# ./localaddr -4 enp0s3
192.168.9.10
[root@localhost]~# echo $?
0
```

But that would be pretty similar to using a Perl module, which probably uses a similar interface to get the goods.

You could also ask that the `ip` folks return a non-zero exit code, maybe when a flag is set, if there is not an address.

Otherwise, you'll probably have to do a more expensive calculation involving more commands:

```
[root@localhost]~# ip -json
Option "-json" is unknown, try "ip -help".
```

... which is not present on Centos 7 so portability to older Linux may be problematic here. Meanwhile on a less historic Linux system,

```
[root@localhost]~# ip -4 -json addr show dev enp0s3 | jq -e '.[].addr_info[].local' ; echo $?
"192.168.9.11"
0
[root@localhost]~# ip -4 -json addr show dev enp0s8 | jq -e '.[].addr_info[].local' ; echo $?
4
```

... but firing up a shell pipeline instead of running a single program seems less efficient to me, so I probably would not use it.

Comment: That `jq` trick may be the best possible solution, at least so far as `ip` returns 0 no matter what. Sadly, it is not available on the environment I'm working with.

Answer (score 1):

## Your question

Answering you is difficult because your question is:

> How would you best solve this?

"this" being:

> `ip -o` skips over any interface without an IP

but I don't know what your are trying to achieve exactly, so that my answer may or may not meet your purpose here.

## My answer

Anyway, **if you want to list every interface whether they have an IP address or not use `ip link` instead of `ip addr`**:

```sh
ip -o link show  # will list all interfaces
ip -o link show dev eth1  # will show eth1
```

This will give you MAC address, up/down status and some other info.

### Why it didn't work

The `-o` flag shows one result per line. If you ask to see addresses, it will iterate on the list of addresses and show you *one address per line*, **or nothing** if there are no addresses to iterate over.

Comment: I think the main issue as far as I was concerned is that `ip -o addr show dev eth1` will return 0 (success) while *no such address exists*.

Comment: I think what I really wanted was a way to avoid `ifconfig` which would entail parsing lots of lines. That said, perl has some wizardry to make it less painful.

Comment: @Lucky you still don't say what your are trying to achieve by parsing this data. I still don't know your goal here so that I cannot think with you of an appropriate solution. Help me help you is what I'm saying here.

Comment: I am looking for the easiest possible way to list all interfaces regardless of configuration state of said interfaces.

Comment: @Lucky If that is so, go for `ip -o link show`.